# Temporary file in memory for python doc to docx conversion

Tags: python, dataframe, docx, temporary-files

I have a lot of doc files that I have to convert into Dataframes. My doc files cannot be converted directly because I get an error message:
`Test.doc' is not a Word file, content type is 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.themeManager+xml`.
If I convert my doc files into docx, I can extract the data into a dataframe.

The problem is that the function I'm using requires a path to a docx file (output_file) for converting and I have to remove the docx file through code at the end. I'd prefer to store the docx data in memory and extract data from it to the dataframe. I've tried BytesIO, IOBase, NamedTemporaryFile, Temporary zip etc. with no success.

If there's a way to convert doc to dataframe directly, that'd make things a lot easier (I've tried most of the popular libraries) or please let me know the temporary file option. I'm attaching my function below.

```
word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(input_file)
doc.SaveAs(output_file, FileFormat=16)
return_dataframe = docx_to_dataframe(output_file)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
os.remove(output_file)
```

Comment: Have you tried copying the contents of the doc to the clipboard and using [`pandas.read_clipboard()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html#pandas-read-clipboard)?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar use case, and this is the solution I came up with until I find something better...

I basically needed to 1) decode the doc files from base64 format 2)read the 'file' in memory which results in a mix of characters in unicode. 3) use regex to capture the text. Here is how I did it:

```
import olefile
#retrieve base64 image and decode into bytes, in this case from a df
message = row['text']
text_bytes = message.encode('ascii')
decoded = base64.decodebytes(text_bytes)
#write in memory
result = BytesIO()
result.write(decoded)
#open and read file
ole=olefile.OleFileIO(result)
y = ole.openstream('WordDocument').read()
y=y.decode('latin-1',errors='ignore')
#replace all characters that are not part of the unicode list below (all latin characters) and spaces with an Astrisk. This can probably be shortened using a similar pattern used in the next step and combining them
y=(re.sub(r'[^\x0A,\u00c0-\u00d6,\u00d8-\u00f6,\u00f8-\u02af,\u1d00-\u1d25,\u1d62-\u1d65,\u1d6b-\u1d77,\u1d79-\u1d9a,\u1e00-\u1eff,\u2090-\u2094,\u2184-\u2184,\u2488-\u2490,\u271d-\u271d,\u2c60-\u2c7c,\u2c7e-\u2c7f,\ua722-\ua76f,\ua771-\ua787,\ua78b-\ua78c,\ua7fb-\ua7ff,\ufb00-\ufb06,\x20-\x7E]',r'*', y))
#Isolate the body of the text from the rest of the gibberish
p=re.compile(r'\*{300,433}((?:[^*]|\*(?!\*{14}))+?)\*{15,}')
result=(re.findall(p, y))
#remove * left in the capture group
result = result[0].replace('*','')
```

For me, I needed to make sure that during decoding, accent characters are not lost, and since my documents are in English, Spanish, and Portuguese, I opted to decode using latin-1. From there I use regex patterns to identify the text needed. After decoding, I found that in all of my documents, the capture group is preceeded by ~400 '*' and a ':' . Unsure if this is the norm for all doc documents when decoding using this method, but I used this as a starting point to create a regex pattern to isolate the text needed from the rest of the gibberish.